# which letter to use for a CFT?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, notation

In math, one says "let $G$ be a group", "let $A$ be an algebra", ...

For groups, the typical letters are $G$, $H$, $K$, ...
For algebras, the typical letters are $A$, $B$, ...

> I want to say things such as "let xxx be a conformal field theory"
>  and "let xxx $\subset$ xxx be a conformal inclusion".

Which letters should I use?
 What is the usual way people go about this?

Here, I'm mostly thinking about chiral CFTs, but the question is also relevant for full (modular invariant) CFTs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I thought conformal inclusions apply to groups (like $SU(2)\subset SO(5)$) and not entire CFT's? Or is this a seperate definition?

Comment: In VOA language, I would call a conformal inclusion a map $V\to W$ of VOAs that sends the Virasoro element of $V$ to the Virasoro element of $W$. But you're right, I've only seen the terminology used for the VOAs that correspond to loop groups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is, I think, no really standard symbol for the generic (chiral) CFT used universally, but there is within the different formalizations.

- When chiral CFTs are modeled by vertex operator algebras, the standard symbol is usually "$V$" (for obvious reasons) as user388027 notes in his reply..
- When chiral CFTs are modeled as conformal nets, then (as you know), the standard symbol is usually "$\mathcal{A}$" or "$\mathfrak{A}$" (for **A** lgebra of observables)

  A randomly picked standard reference with this usage is Gabbiani,Fröhlich, *[Operator algebras and CFT](http://pages.uoregon.edu/njp/GF.pdf)*

It seems to me that most authors who need and use the notion of CFT more abstractly tend to write things like

$$
  CFT_1 \to CFT_2
$$

For instance so [here](http://hep.physics.uoc.gr/conf09/TALKS/Bachas.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

Ben-Zvi & Frenkel denote vertex algebras $V$,$W$,... They're using the labels specifically for the spaces of states, but one could also use them to refer the whole package.

Alternately, one sometimes sees all caps abbreviations: $YM_2$, $SYM_{4,G}$,...

There is not to my knowledge any conventional notation for morphisms of field theories.

Answer (score 6):

For conformal nets $\mathcal A,\mathcal B,\ldots$ or $A,B,\ldots$ is typical. For Virasoro nets $\mathrm{Vir}_{c=\frac 12}$ is normally used and for loop group nets $\mathcal A_{G_k}$. In VOA it seems to be common to use 
$V$
for a generic VOA. Kac uses in "VOA for Beginners" $V_Q$ for the lattice VOA associated with a lattice $Q$ and $V^k(\mathfrak g)$ for the affice VOA of $\mathfrak g$ at level $k$.